# Create custom component in PrimeFaces 4

Tags: jsf, primefaces, custom-component

I will create a custom component for PrimeFaces 4.
I don't know any thing about this and need a step by step tutorial. So I google it and find a PDF (chapter 11 of packt PrimeFaces cookbook).
But this is for PrimeFaces 3.
can you give me a good link or tutorial for create it.
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good resource to start : [extending-primefaces-components](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-web/primefaces/extending-primefaces-components)

Glad to be helpful.

Comment: thanks. it is helpful. do you have any other links like this. thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. There isn't so much resources online. I found [this book](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/learning-primefaces-extensions/9781783983247/), maybe can help you.